# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rotator is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have reviewed other errors similar to this, and the answers, which each one was tailored per question.  I am stumped here, hoping someone can figure this out, 1 week building this and hopefully not stopped because of a silly character or 2.

I get the above mentioned with the following codes:

```
    =======================The JS code in question====================
      /* Title Rotator */
  var options = {
      "speed": 4000, // Rotate every 4 seconds
      "transition_speed": 500, // Fade in/out has a .5 second duration
      "sub_selector": ".rotate"
  };
  jQuery.noConflict();
  $("#rotate").rotator(options);

  /*Firefly*/
   $.firefly({
    color: '#fff',
      minPixel: 1,
      maxPixel: 3,
      total : 45,
    on: '#firefly'
 });


=========================The HTML===========================

              <!doctype html> 
 <!-- ====================Now to make this site work with IE versions 6,7,
 and 8==================================  -->  
 <!--[if IE 6 ]><html lang="en-us" class="ie6"> <![endif]--> 
 <!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en-us" class="ie7"> <![endif]--> 
 <!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en-us" class="ie8"> <![endif]--> 
 <!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!--> 
 <html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
 <!--<![endif]-->

           <!-- ===========================================End IE coding==========================================  --
```

```
          <!-- ======================================Mobile Metas=============================================== --> 

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- ======================================Google Fonts=============================================== --> 

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

   <!-- ======================================RBrogan Modals stylesheet=================================== -->


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/rbrogan.code.css">

   <!-- ======================================Normalized CSS============================================= -->                
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">




 <!-- ========Code copied to jquery.RBrogan-modals.min.js to speed response of site====================

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

 ======================================================================================================= -->


 <!-- ==========================Mix in a little RBrogan JavaScript and...=============================== -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.RBrogan-modals.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



  <!-- =====================================Let us Load the Page Now==================================== -->
```

```
 <body class="preload">

 <!-- ======================================Background Slider Image====================================== -->

  <div id="kenburns-bg"></div>

 <!-- ======================================END Background Slider Image================================== -->

 <!-- ======================================Let's through down an Overlay================================ -->       




  <div id="firefly" class="bg-overlay">
    <canvas id="star-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>

 <!-- ======================================That's it, now lets End Overlay============================== -->      

  <!-- =====================================Header======================================================= --> 
  <header>
     <div class="intro">

     <!-- ========== This is were the magic happens ========== -->
    <div id="popup-1" class="rbModal">
        <div class="window">

            <!--  popup content -->
            <iframe id="myVideo" 
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vsObnzivL1A?&rel=0&loop=1&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0&hd=1&autohide=1&color=white&wmode=opaque" 
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
            <!-- / popup content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ========== Wasn't that cool? ========== -->

   <!-- ====================================Show my Awesome Site Logo==================================== -->

        <div class="logo"><img src="images/RB logo-horizantal-shadowdrop-final.png" alt="twist" /></div>

   <!-- ====================================End Site Logo and continuing on with AWESOME================= -->

   <!-- ============================Now, Let us animate some text and call it "Rotator Title"============ --> 

        <div id="rotate">
           <h1 class="rotate">RAYMOND<span> BROGAN</span><br><span>WEB | </span> AUDIO | <span>VIDEO </span></h1>
           <h1 class="rotate">We <span>Envision</span>. We <span>Design</span><br>We <span>Bring to Life</span>. Your Ideas</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- End Rotator Title -->

        <p>We are Coming</p>
        <p><span></span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span></span></p>
        <p>Really Soon</p>

     </div>
     <!-- Nav -->
     <nav>
        <ul class="navigation">
           <li class="link left middle side move"><a href="#about" title="About">About</a></li>
           <li class="link right middle side move"><a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
           <li class="link center bottom move"><a class="btn" href="#subscribe" title="Subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
     <!-- End Nav -->
  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->

  <!-- About Section -->
  <section id="about" data-direction="from-left">
     <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        <h1>
           <span>About Us</span>
        </h1>
        <!-- ./End Section Title -->
        <div class="row text-center">
           <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer dis augue interdum quis a. Pretium habitant et volutpat egestas et elit facilisi et porttitor mauris.</h4>
              <p>Sed wisi congue egestas Vestibulum et augue mi et Vivamus Cum. Penatibus laoreet Nullam sagittis metus turpis non mus facilisi Sed justo. Libero felis tellus molestie Aliquam orci elit et pretium ac consectetuer. Vestibulum mus mollis Vestibulum augue sagittis convallis sit at nec a. Vitae Vestibulum Quisque facilisis sem Pellentesque dui quis augue amet sapien. Enim Nullam Sed tortor sem pellentesque cursus malesuada lacus eget sapien. Wisi porttitor Suspendisse.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End About Section -->

  <!-- Subscribe Section -->
  <section id="subscribe" data-direction="from-bottom">
     <div class="content">
        <h1>
           <span>Subscribe</span>
        </h1>
        <!-- ./End Section Title -->
        <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row text-center">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                 <!-- Subscribe form -->                
                 <div class="subscribe form-wrap">
                    <form action="#" method="post" id="subscribe-form">
                       <p class="form-field">
                          <input type="text" name="email" id="subscribe_email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"/>
                       </p>
                       <p class="form-submit">
                          <input type="submit" name="subscribe_submit" id="subscribe_submit" value="" />
                       </p>
                       <span id="response"></span>
                    </form>
                    <p>We will notify you, when the site will launched. We don't do any spam with your email address.</p>
                 </div>
                 <!-- End Subscribe form-->     
                 <div class="social">
                    <a href="#" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Dribble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Flickr"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Github"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Subscribe Section -->

  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <section id="contact" data-direction="from-right">
     <div class="container">           
        <h1>
           <span>Contact</span>
        </h1>
        <!-- ./End Section Title -->
        <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <h4>Just want to say hello? Send me an email or fill out the form below and we will get back to you ASAP.</h4>
              <!-- Begin Phone -->
              <div class="newline col-sm-4 text-center">
                 <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i>
                 <br>
                 +1 (123) 4567890
              </div>
              <!-- End Phone -->
              <!-- Begin Email -->
              <div class="newline col-sm-4 text-center">
                 <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
                 <br>
                 info@example.com
              </div>
              <!-- End Email -->
              <!-- Begin Address -->
              <div class="newline col-sm-4 text-center">
                 <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                 <br>
                 Twist Agency
                 <br>
                 Paltan Tower, Dhaka.
              </div>
              <!-- End Address -->
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="contactForm">
              <!-- Start Contact Form -->  
              <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post" role="form">

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="formName" type="text" class="input required" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="formEmail" type="email" class="input required" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" value="" size="30" name="phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <textarea id="message" class="textarea required" name="message" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Your question"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-green-border btn-lg" type="submit">Send</button>
                                </div>

                            </form>
              <div class="successMsg"></div>
              <!-- End Contact Form -->
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Contact Section -->

  <!-- Loading... -->        
  <div id="preload">
     <div id="preload-content">
        <div class="preload-bounce">                           
           <span class="bounce1">
           </span>                         
           <span class="bounce2">
           </span>                         
           <span class="bounce3">
           </span>                   
           <span class="bounce4">
           </span>                   
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ==============================================
     JS
     =============================================== -->            
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>     
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>           
  <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.kenburnsy.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/star.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried making the jQuery reference local? I mean, download the Jquery and reference it. Also, why is jQuery commented out? You need it in order to use jQuery as far as I know

Comment: where you include rotator plugin ?

Comment: Loading order isn't right. Can't load `jqueryUI` before `jQuery`

Comment: @Octanic jQuery is included (otherwise, the error will be `$ is not defined`). That isn't included is the `rotator` plugin, it's because `rotator is not a function`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Not necessarily, Marcos. If any of his javascript declares $ as a function, this behavior would be overriden. Turns out the third party library was missing. Also, check out the comment on the other answer...

Comment: You're right. This seems to be a question for wizards or adivinations. What third library is missing? Nobody knows.... LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting rotator to do? As far as I'm aware it isn't part of the jQuery UI library. It looks like it requires a third party library which I don't think you've included.

Comment: The rotator is an image to close the auto open video box

Comment: Wow, something so simple, I forgot to include the third party Library

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I said it requires a third party library which he hasn't in luded. That's the answer

Comment: @ThomasIllingworth I said exactly the same in the comments of the post. But OP doesn't seem to read the comments. I said `That isn't included is the rotator plugin, it's because rotator is not a function`

Comment: you are right, I didnt read the comments, I'm new, My apologies

Answer (score 0):

When you use `jQuery.noConflict();`, jQuery will relinquish $. So, you can only access jQuery to use `jQuery` not `$` .

more information see [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: I had it as `$.noConflict(); `, but the error moved to it saying that the $ wasnt a function

Comment: @R.Brogan Maybe you should put `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` at the first I guess. And remove `$.noConflict();` if want to access jQuery with `$`